# Adding custom components into Material-ui Select

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

So, I'm trying to add `<Button />` inside Material-ui `<Select />` component **(it should close the drop-down dialog when I click on the button)** but the problem is that the button behaves as a `<MenuItem />` component and i can`t set behavior i need.

> Is anyone tried to customize select like so?
>   Any ideas?

Comment: You can use with react-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you wrap the buttons in a `<div>` under `<MenuItem/>`s. For example,

```
<Select>
  <MenuItem>1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>2</MenuItem>
  <div>
    <button onClick={()=>console.log('close button clicked')}>close</button>
  </div>
</Select>
```

I've created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-buttons-1tpwc)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a boolean type variable that the Select components 'open' prop is dependent on(defaulted to false), then use the 'onOpen' prop to set that same boolean to true.

Now inside the Select component, wrap a MenuItem component around a Button component. This Button components 'onClick' prop will need to set the boolean that your Select components 'open' prop is dependent on, to false.